# How to Search specific Tabitem Header which is created dynamically ? - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating tabitems dynamically. Kindly tell me how can I search specific tabitem Header irrespective of tabitem selected. Actually I want to make sure that tabitem won't be duplicate when i'm creating new tabitem..
Following is the pseudo code which I want..

```
foreach(var tabitem in tabcontrl.items)
{
if(newHeader == tabitem.Header){
//do nothing
}
else{
tabControl.Items.Add(newTabItem(newHeader));
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you create the `TabItems` and how you set the `Header` property.

If you add `TabItem` elements to the `TabControl` explicitly in the XAML markup like this:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="..." />
</TabControl>
```

...this should work:

```
if (!tabControl.Items.OfType<TabItem>().Any(x => x.Header?.ToString() == newHeader))
    tabControl.Items.Add(new TabItem() { Header = newHeader } );
```

If you use MVVM and bind the `TabControl` to a source collection, you should iterate through this collection:

```
sourceCollection.Any(x => x.HeaderSourceProperty == newHeader)
```